# How to explicit override server port on project created via fastify-cli using typescript template?

Tags: typescript, fastify

By using fastify-cli to create a project, the app.js contains a inicialization in form of plugin:

```
import './pre-start'; 
import { join } from 'path';
import AutoLoad, {AutoloadPluginOptions} from '@fastify/autoload';
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';

export type AppOptions = {
  // Place your custom options for app below here.
} & Partial<AutoloadPluginOptions>;


// Pass --options via CLI arguments in command to enable these options.
const options: AppOptions = {
}

const app: FastifyPluginAsync<AppOptions> = async (
    fastify,
    opts
): Promise<void> => {
  // Place here your custom code!

  // Do not touch the following lines

  // This loads all plugins defined in plugins
  // those should be support plugins that are reused
  // through your application
  void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
    options: opts
  })

  // This loads all plugins defined in routes
  // define your routes in one of these
  void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
    options: opts
  })

};

export default app;
export { app, options }
```

However, there is no reference to the server listening itself, hence no place to override the port explicitly in the code.

I am using dotenv but I am choosing the correct .env file to be loaded (development.env, test.env, production.env). It is basically the approach I am used to following in expressjs (I am migrating my project), so I import the file './pre-start' at the first line of the app.js, that configures dotenv with the correct env file. In the scope of app.js, if I trace the environment variable PORT I can see the value I want, but when I execute the project, fastify ignores this configuration and load the server with default port 3000, and as there is no explicit way to set the port, what should I do here?

Content of pre-start.ts

```
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import commandLineArgs from 'command-line-args';
 
const options = commandLineArgs([
  {
    name: 'env',
    alias: 'e',
    defaultValue: 'development',
    type: String,
  },
]);
 

const result2 = dotenv.config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, `../env/${String(options.env)}.env`),
});
 
if (result2.error) {
  throw result2.error;
}
```

NPM commands

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run build:ts && tsc -p test/tsconfig.json && tap --ts \"test/**/*.test.ts\"",
    "start": "npm run build:ts && fastify start -l info dist/app.js",
    "build:ts": "tsc",
    "watch:ts": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "npm run build:ts && concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"TypeScript,App\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold\" \"npm:watch:ts\" \"npm:dev:start\"",
    "dev:start": "fastify start --ignore-watch=.ts$ -w -l info -P dist/app.js"
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you add the script you are running to start the application and the directory where you stored the `.env` files?

Comment: Thanks @ManuelSpigolon I've added more information to the topic. If I place a .env file at the root of the project and define a port there, everything works fine. The problem is, if I override dotenv configuration as you can see above, it will be valid only for my application but will not be considered as a parameter for the server.

Answer (score 2):

ref: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli#options

NOTE:

> By default fastify-cli runs dotenv,
> so it will load all the env variables stored in .env in your current
> working directory.

[image]

[image]

> You can pass the following options via CLI arguments. Every option has
> a corresponding environment variable.

[image: options]

so if you want to change default port, you will have to create a config file and pass it through command line when server is started.

--- package.json ---

```
    "start": "npm run build:ts && fastify start -l info dist/app.js -c \"config.json\"",
```

--- config.json ---

```
{
    "port": 6000
}
```

Note: you will have to use camelCase conventions in the config file :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is indeed a clever solution to have a config file instead of passing the port directly to command line. Although, the initial goal was to read one of the env files and use the parameter in there. I've managed to do that by not using the fastify command above. I instead manually listened to the server instance and I've used the node command instead of the fastify command. If I get it right the fastify command works as a shortcut, but it is possible to do things manually and have the same result

Answer (score 1):

The package fastify-cli can receive some params and from terminal.
You can edit your start and dev command in `package.json` with `--port` (`-p`) option.
Here is an example:

```
fastify start -l info -p 3000 -a 0.0.0.0 app.js
```

In you terminal you can find all option of fastify-cli start with the command

```
fastify start --help
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [@Gambitier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538127/20639985) and [@Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75581923/20639985)'s answers, fastify cli allows parameters to be passed and its initialization even uses dotenv to fetch environment variables. Nevertheless, my requirement is not possible to be achieved by using the cli start command.

According to the documentation, the solution is to [migrate out of fastify-cli](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli#migrating-out-of-fastify-cli-start), by listening the server manually and starting the server with node command. My final code is:

server.ts

```
import { join } from 'path';
import AutoLoad from '@fastify/autoload';
import { fastify } from 'fastify';
import pino from 'pino';
const server = fastify({
  logger: pino({ level: 'info' }),
});

// register plugin below:
void server.register(AutoLoad, {
  dir: join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
});

// This loads all plugins defined in routes
// define your routes in one of these
void server.register(AutoLoad, {
  dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
});

export default server;
```

index.ts

```
import './pre-start'; // Must be the first import, select the appropriate .env file (content in the original post)
import server from './server';

server.listen({ port: Number(process.env.PORT ?? 3000) }); //procces.env.PORT holds the value coming from the expected .env file loaded at pre-start.ts
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -w",,
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
  }
}
```